# Can't serialize custom class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, serializable

I'm pretty new with Xamarin and I'm trying to make an app for Android/iOS. I'm trying to send over a class with a putExtra, so I tried to make the class Serializable by adding the ISerializable interface, but whenever I try to do that I need to implement a Handle() and Dispose() method. I'm not sure what to do with those methods, so they have a NotImplementedException.

When I try to go the next activity I get the NotImplementedException (which most likely comes from the handle or the dispose). I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong with the implementation of my class.

Here is the Event class (which I try to send over to the next Activity):

```
public class Event : Object, ISerializable
{
    private long id;
    private string name;
    private string description;
    private double latitude = 0;
    private double longitude = 0;
    private User author;
    private List<User> participants;
    private List<EventDate> eventDates;

    public Event(long id, string name, string description, double latitude, double longitude, User author, List<User> participants, List<EventDate> eventDates)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.author = author;
        this.participants = participants;
        this.eventDates = eventDates;
    }

    public Event(long id, string name, string description, User author)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.author = author;
        this.participants = new List<User>();
        this.eventDates = new List<EventDate>();
    }

    public long Id
    {
        get { return id; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
    }

    public double Latitude
    {
        get { return latitude; }
    }

    public User Author
    {
        get { return author; }
    }

    public List<User> Participants
    {
        get { return participants; }
    }

    public List<EventDate> EventDates
    {
        get { return eventDates; }
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public EventDate getBestDate()
    {
        EventDate bestDate = null;
        foreach (EventDate date in eventDates)
        {
            if (bestDate == null || date.AvailableUsers.Count > bestDate.AvailableUsers.Count)
            {
                bestDate = date;
            }
        }
        return bestDate;
    }

    public void addParticipant(User participant)
    {
        this.participants.Add(participant);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This class is in the (Portable) project and not in the .Droid project, since I also need it in iOS.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong or maybe suggest an alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have change `ISerializable` to `Java.IO.ISerializable`.

I have Created this way

```
class MySerializable : Object, Java.IO.ISerializable
    {
        public string Value {get; private set;}

        public MySerializable (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base (handle, transfer)
        {
        }

        public MySerializable ()
        {
        }

        public MySerializable (string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
}
```

for more detail visit this :

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.IO.ISerializable/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I already use `Java.IO.Serializable`, but instead of putting it like this I have it imported like `using Java.IO;`

Comment: Changing my code to your code doesn't change anything; I still need Handle() and Dispose() methods which make my app crash because of NotImplementedException.